# Why would you bind the value of a NSProgressIndicator?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings

What's the point of binding the value of a NSProgressIndicator to your controller? It never seems to ask the controller for the value, except on startup. The only way to move the NSProgressIndicator seems to be by sending it #increaseBy:, which bypasses my binding. So, why would I bind?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your UI's bound value not updating, that means you either bungled the binding or your controller code is not modifying the bound value in a key-value-observing–compliant way. The most common problem is doing `fooIvar = val` rather than `[self setFooIvar:val]` or `self.fooIvar = val`.

Apple's answer to your problem:

> ### [What to do if] Changing the value of a model property programmatically is not reflected in the user interface
>
> If changes made to a model value programmatically are not being reflected in the user interface, this typically indicates that the model object is not key-value-observing compliant for the property, or that you are modifying the value in a manner that is bypassing key-value observing. You should ensure that:
>
> - The model class has automatic key-value observing enabled or implements manual key-value observing for the property.
> - That you are changing the value using an accessor method, or using a key-value-coding compliant method. Changing the value of an instance variable directly does not provide key-value observing change notifications.
> - If your model property is a collection, that you're modifying the content in a key-value-observing compliant manner. See “[My collection controller isn’t displaying the current data](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CocoaBindings/Concepts/Troubleshooting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002148-182809)” for more information.

For that answer and answers other common problems, see ["Troubleshooting Cocoa Bindings."](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CocoaBindings/Concepts/Troubleshooting.html)

You should also look at [the examples provided by mmalc.](http://homepage.mac.com/mmalc/CocoaExamples/controllers.html) They are a valuable resource.